# Using pygooglevoice with IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, google-voice

I'm trying to wrap pygooglevoice with a pretty C# Winform app 
using IronPython.  I'm VERY new to python and I've overcome a few 
hurdles, but it looks like I need an experts eyes (or a beginners!) 
(or an 'expats' eyes) to assist me with this one.

```
 File "..\googlevoice\util.py", line 3, 
in <module> 
ImportError: cannot import expat from xml.parsers 
The actual code here is: 
from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate
```

I get the above error when executing the IronPython ipy64.exe as 
follows:

```
ip64.exe "c:\Users\nick\Downloads\pygooglevoice-0.5\googlevoice\markasread.py
```

The contents of markasread.py are as follows:

```
from googlevoice import Voice,util 
voice = Voice() 
voice.login('emailAddr...@gmail.com', 'password here') 
while True : 
    folder = voice.search('is:unread') 
    if folder.totalSize <= 0 : 
        break 
    util.print_(folder.totalSize) 
    for message in folder.messages: 
        util.print_(message) 
        message.mark(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

well, seems the googlevoice api uses the expat parser, which isn't supported by IronPython.

maybe you can get it to work if you use the [`pyexpat`](http://fepy.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fepy/trunk/lib/pyexpat.py?content-type=text%2Fplain) from [FePy](http://fepy.sourceforge.net/) instead (save it as `Lib/xml/parsers/expat.py`). but i don't know if that's enough to get everything to work.